Do I understand correctly that Ubuntu Live USB - just like Kali Linux and Tails - will delete all its traces after finishing work?
I just need an anonymous system. I tried to install Kali Linux for 3 days and almost 20 attempts and I couldn't. Only Live USB, but that's complicated. I've never dealt with Linux. Anonymity is important to me.
I need it to erase everything after removing the flash drive or shutting down.
For stability and greater habituation, I also want to install the same version of Linux on a hard drive partition, and also leave Windows on one partition just in case.
Will I be able to implement it here?
Is there a comparison of Linux versions somewhere? Do they all definitely completely delete all traces of their presence in Live USB mode?

I regularly use Ubuntu live systems on borrowed devices (ie. hardware I don't own & cannot make any changes to; and promise not to attempt to mount any local drives) and the only consequence I've ever experienced is the system clock has been changed (Ubuntu being a network aware OS assumes UTC time; windows kept standard of MS-DOS which assumes local time as not-internet aware by default). Some enterprise hardware records all external hardware boots (in machine logs) so that trace will exist too (need hardware admin access to remove that) but this isn't OS specific.

This is Ubuntu Q&A support site and not a Linux support. Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   The Ubuntu system I'm using on this PC differs to the Linux my phone runs (Android), different to what's in my motorcar (Automotive Grade Linux) etc

Also don't forget (as alluded to on first comment) that machine hardware differs in what it records.. If someone booted live Ubuntu system on the PC I'm using now whilst it was turned off & I was away; I'd expect to never know... HOWEVER I have other hardware that will give will record details because the machine firmware records all boots (with more detail for external media!)
